# Take the last X entries in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, csv, spreadsheet

I am taking data from a spreadsheet, that is updated every week, and 10 entries are added to the end of the spreadsheet. Im making a seperate spreasheet, that collects this data and uses it. How can I get excel to call the last X, or in my case 10, entries from the spreadsheet.

Comment: Get the `lastrow` with `=LOOKUP(2;1/(A:A<>"");ROW(A:A))` and to get the value of last cell `=INDEX(A:A;LOOKUP(2;1/(A:A<>"");ROW(A:A)))` so for the first item it is `=INDEX(A:A;LOOKUP(2;1/(A:A<>"");ROW(A:A))-9)`

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. For those who are wanting to do this. I used the INDEX Function like so:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C, COUNTA(Data!C:C)-9, 1)
```

and carried this on for the next 10 cells with each cell a cell higher like so:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C, COUNTA(Data!C:C)-8, 1)
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C, COUNTA(Data!C:C)-7, 1)
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C, COUNTA(Data!C:C)-6, 1)
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

try

```
=INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)-ROWS(J23:$J$32),1)
```

The ROWS element makes it dynamic to just drag down